# Query que retorne vários resultados

Tags: query

Eu tenho está Query `MtDispositivo.where("id_conta = ?", "28")` que me retorna todas as contas que apresentam o ID_CONTA = **28**.

Abaixo tenho estas outras Querys que me retornam mesmo resultado que são contas com `ID_CONTA` tal.

```
 MtDispositivo.where("id_conta = ?", "29")

 MtDispositivo.where("id_conta = ?", "30")

 MtDispositivo.where("id_conta = ?", "36")
```

Preciso fazer uma Query com todas estes `IDS_CONTAS` que me retornem todas as contas que contenham apenas estas IDS: **28**, **29**, **30** e **36**.

E depois preciso adicionar uma sessão Download, onde será feito download destas contas em Excel.

Podem me ajudar? Entenderam a pergunta?

---

Tenho um Dispositivo chamado MtDispositivo onde ele armazena todas contas.

Preciso fazer uma Query com estes `ID_CONTAS: 28, 29, 30 e 36` que retornem estás contas.

Quando fiz `MtDispositivo.where("id_conta = ?", "29")` ele retorna apenas as contas que contêm `ID_CONTA 29`.

Invés de ficar fazendo de um em um preciso de uma Query onde eu possa pegar todos os resultados de vários IDS de vez.

São os IDS: 28, 29, 30 e 36.

Comment: está utilizando que tecnologias?

Comment: Estou utilizando Ruby on Rails. preciso pegar estes ID_CONTA pelo terminal Linux.

Depois criar um trecho de código onde os clientes possam fazer download destes IDS em Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Não deu para entender muito bem a pergunta, mas aparentemente o operador IN do sql te ajuda.

```
select * from tabela where id_conta IN (28, 29, 30, 36)
```

Answer (score 0):

So complementando a resposta acima, voce pode usar o IN.

Pra gerar o download, voce vai ter que utilizar csv.
Eu possuo um sistema que lida com clientes.
O codigo para gerar o csv dele esta abaixo:

```
#Generate the CSV file
def self.to_csv(distributor_id)
    sql = "SELECT * FROM customer_breakdown WHERE distributor_id = '#{distributor_id}' ORDER BY reference_date DESC"
    @customers = {}
    @customers = CustomerBreakdown.find_by_sql(sql)
    CSV.generate do |csv|
        csv << ["iccid", "unique_id", "total_revenue", "call_usage", "sms_usage", "data_usage", "packages_purchased", "forwarding_numbers", "vouchers_applied", "reference_date"]
        @customers.each do |customer|
            csv << [customer.iccid, customer.unique_id, customer.total_revenue, customer.call_usage, customer.sms_usage, customer.data_usage, customer.packages_purchased, customer.forwarding_numbers, customer.vouchers_applied, customer.reference_date]
        end
    end
end
```

No primeiro csv << voce vai colocar o nome das colunas, e no segundo os valores que vao aparecer em cada linha nas respectivas colunas.

Esse codigo deve ir no seu model.
Depois disso, no seu controller voce tem que definir uma funcao que irar gerar o csv.
      def generate_csv

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.csv{ send_data CustomerBreakdown.to_csv(current_user.id) }
end
```

end

Neste caso a resposta para essa chamada sera no formato csv. Feito isso basta voce gerar um botao na sua view que chama o caminho generate_csv.
Lembre de ajeitar os parametros de acordo com sua necessidade